# post_count for only posts with thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

how to edit this condition in order to count only the posts with thumbnails?

```
if ( $my_query->have_posts() && ( ( $my_query->post_count ) >= 3 ) )
```

Comment: can people understand from one line of code?

Comment: i think it's clear, i want to count the posts with thumbnail instead of counting posts

Comment: @Akam Yes. Those are WordPress functions. Still... it's a bad question, and easily answered by reading the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check it in a different way;

```
$post_with_thumbs = 0;
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ( $my_query->have_posts() ): $my_query->the_post();
    if (  has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $post_with_thumbs++;
        }
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();

if ($post_with_thumbs >= 3) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must do the loop, because thumbnail relationships are not resolved automatically:

```
$postsWithThumbs = 0;

while($my_query->have_posts()){
  $my_query->the_post();

  if(has_post_thumbnail())
    $postsWithThumbs++;
}

wp_reset_postdata();

print $postsWithThumbs;
```

Comment: what's the deference between wp_reset_postdata and wp_reset_query?!

Comment: `wp_reset_query` should be used when you modify the main query (`query_posts` does that), and you want to restore both the query and globals. Yours seems to be custom loop, so it's enough to reset just the globals

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this still works, but from [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/query-posts-based-on-if-has-post-thumbnail) you can select posts with a thumbnail by specifying `meta_key=_thumbnail_id` in your original query.